# Appropriate use of Stack Overflow responses

Tags: discussion, licensing

What is the appropriate use / attribution / non-use / licensing of responses to questions posted on SO?

Is the information provided by the user community (e.g., code examples or solutions to posed problems) available for use in a commercial code base?

What is the practice that is generally followed for using code segments posted here in external code bases?

Does it matter if it is one line of code (e.g., how to subset a dataframe) vs something more developed (e.g., a solution of 20 or 30 lines of code displayed here)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service

Comment: Posts are licensed under [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/). See [Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @jonrsharpe @D M  Thank you very much. These are just the kinds of discussions I was hoping to find.

Comment: I don't see a way to close this question, but the posts identified in the above comments close this question for me. Thanks

Comment: @bici.sancta you do not need to do anything to close the question - it's already been closed by 5 close voters (myself included). If you have a question that has *pending* close votes, but not closed, you can always vote to close it, and your vote will be "binding" (immediate closure).